# MinuteProject First Trial java.net.url nullpointer exception

Tags: jdbc, frameworks, openxava

I am trying to use minuteproject to generate openxava files. My config is the similar to the one in http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/OpenXava demo file. 
I get java.net.url exception. I checked my jdbc url and couldn't find an error. This is my first trial with minuteproject. I want to learn it very much because I was looking for a framework like this (minuteproject + openxava) for a long time. Thank you for your time :)
Ferda

I will add my config file here. I try to reverse engineer only one file not whole database. My database is MS SQL.

```
<!DOCTYPE root>
<generator-config>
    <configuration>
        <model name="evrak" version="1.0" package-root="veritabani.xxx.org.tr">
            <data-model>
                <dataSource>
                    <driverClassName>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driverClassName>
                    <url>jdbc:sqlserver://10.1.x.x:1433;DataBaseName=xxx</url>
                    <username>xx</username>
                    <password>xx</password>
                </dataSource>
                <!-- for Oracle and DB2 please set the schema
                <schema> </schema>
                 -->
                <primaryKeyPolicy oneGlobal="true" oneForEachTable="false">
                    <primaryKeyPolicyPattern prefix="" suffix="" name="sequencePattern" sequenceName="hibernate_sequence"></primaryKeyPolicyPattern>
                    <!-- for autogenerated pk (mysql)
                    <primaryKeyPolicyPattern name="autoincrementPattern" ></primaryKeyPolicyPattern>
                    -->
                </primaryKeyPolicy>
            </data-model>
            <business-model>
                <generation-condition>
                    <condition type="exclude" startsWith="DUAL"></condition>
                    <condition type="exclude" startsWith="ID_GEN"></condition>
            <condition type="include" startsWith="dbo.sekreterya_kisifirma" ></condition>
         <condition type="exclude" startsWith="ID_GEN"></condition>


sekreterya_kisifirma
                </generation-condition>
                <business-package default="veritabani.losev.org.tr">
                </business-package>
            </business-model>
        </model>
        <targets catalog-entry="OpenXava"/>
    </configuration>
</generator-config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without the stacktrace, it is a bit hard to investigate.

Meanwhile, since you want to use minuteproject with openxava on top of mssql database, I advise you to follow a sample at [northwind-db-revisited-with-mp-4-ox](http://minuteproject.blogspot.be/2013/08/northwind-db-revisited-with-mp-4-ox.html).

It generates an openxava application on top of the famous northwind database.

To summary the datamodel access configuration, inspire yourself from

```
<dataSource>
 <driverClassName>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driverClassName>
 <url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=northwind</url>
 <username>sqlserver</username>
 <password>xxxxxxxx</password>
</dataSource>
<!-- for Oracle and DB2 please set the schema <schema> </schema> -->
<schema>dbo</schema>
<primaryKeyPolicy oneGlobal="true">
 <primaryKeyPolicyPattern name="identityPattern"></primaryKeyPolicyPattern>
</primaryKeyPolicy>
```

Do not forget to set the schema node to dbo

Comment: Hi, xflorian can you please upvote the question. I have issues related to the number of questions with 0 votes. This problem causes me not entering new questions.